# How to form a query for a given data structure with dexie

Tags: dexie

I didn't found an answer for the following problem.

The following data structure is given. I want to find out the time (30) for the pressure at 8500. I dont't know how to form the query there for.

Could anybody help me? Thank you.

kind regards

```
my_db.version(1).stores({  
    hose: "++, &deviceId, hoseName, *meassuredValues"  

my_db.open().then(function () {  
    my_db.hose.add({  
    deviceId: "11",  
    hoseName: "DN 20",  
    meassuredValues: [  
        { pressure: 10000, time: 0 },  
        { pressure: 9958, time: 10 },  
        { pressure: 9000, time: 20 },  
        { pressure: 8500, time: 30 },  
        { pressure: 8000, time: 40 },  
    ]  
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you target only Chrome, Opera, Firefox and Safari 10, use compound indexes. You'd index your data with [time+pressure] which is a combination of time and pressure and then query

```
my_db.hose.where('[time+pressure]').equals([30, 8500]).toArray();
```

If you need to target IE, Edge and Safari < 10, you'll need to pick one index and add a JS filter of the rest:

```
my_db.hose.where('pressure').equals(8500).and(function (x) {
    return x.time === 30;
}).toArray();
```

Comment: Hello David,

thank you for help. It should work like that: A user wants to know the time for the pressure 8500. He puts this value (8500) into an input field and dexie has to search the corresponding time.

The data base is like a look-up-table. Can you help me once more? Thank you

kind regards Achim

Comment: ...my_db.hose.where('pressure').equals(8500)... ist empty. There is a key(key path) 'meassuredValues', but there is no object inside. I don't know why.

Comment: Seems correct. Are you sure you have the data in your db? How are you executing your query? Using toArray (), each () or first () ? Are you consuming the resulting Promise correctly?

Comment: I use each:
`my_db.hose.where('pressure').equals("8500").each(function (result) {
            console.log("time: " + result.time);
        });`

But it seems, as if there is a mistake in my data structure. I get the following error message:
_italic_"Unhandled rejection: SchemaError: KeyPath pressure on object store hose is not indexed"

Comment: Ok, that's because you need to index 'pressure'  in your schema the same way you've indexed hoseName.